# Node Elasticsearch module search not returning results

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm setting up a project with node (v 12.4.0) and elasticsearch (7.4.0) using [the official module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch).

I'm attempting to search using

```
import { Client, RequestParams, ApiResponse } from '@elastic/elasticsearch'

const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' })
const params: RequestParams.Search = { index: 'doc', body: { query: { match: { title: "castle" } } } };
const response: ApiResponse = await client.search(params);
```

This gives a 200 response, but no results.

Attempting the same thing using Postman returns the 1 result.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": { "title": "castle" }
    }
}
```

I'm not having any luck figuring out why the `search` function is not working.  I've also tested `get`, `add`, and `delete`, which all work.

To create the index, I used:

```
await client.indices.create({ index: "doc" });
```

To add a document, I use:

```
await client.index({
    index: 'doc',
    body: {
        title: "Castle Title",
        body: "This is text that is not the title."
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this and it works, the only thing is that elasticsearch is near real-time searchable. You need to wait 1 second before the document becomes searchable.
Basically, if you are running a test or something, where you save the record just before searching you need to either:

1. wait for 1 second before searching
2. trigger a manual refresh https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html
3. wait for it to be refreshed when saving https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

Comment: This was the problem.  I have the tests setup to clear the db by deleting and re-creating the index. Adding `await client.indices.refresh({ index: "doc" });` fixes everything.